# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ModelTranslator

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have been scratching my head for weeks now trying to figure this out.

I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError trying to initialize a SOAP webservice which was generated from a WSDL file using [wsdl2java from Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html).

The problem only appears on our production environment, and it comes and goes with different deployments. Some deployments it works fine, and other it doesn't, even though the code doesn't change.

Stacktrace:

```
Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ModelTranslator
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ModelTranslator
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicies(BuilderHandler.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicySubjects(BuilderHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.doPopulate(BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.java:42)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.populate(BuilderHandler.java:52)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getNewPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:79)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:61)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.postFinished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:939)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.postFinished(DelegatingParserExtension.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.postFinished(WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:306)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:148)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:334)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:201)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:182)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:89)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:112)
    at forecast.logic.timelog.projectservice.ProjectManagementServiceSecure.(ProjectManagementServiceSecure.java:47)
    at forecast.logic.timelog.TimeLogClient.getProjectService(TimeLogClient.java:187)
    at forecast.logic.timelog.TimeLogInstantTaskLogic.createTaskInTimeLog(TimeLogInstantTaskLogic.java:70)
    at forecast.logic.TaskLogic.createTask(TaskLogic.java:486)
    at forecast.logic.TaskLogic.createJiraTask(TaskLogic.java:5704)
    at forecast.server.Task.createJiraTask(Task.java:369)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

After looking through similar questions/answers here on StackOverflow I have tried adding different dependencies that have worked for other people, so my pom now looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Do any of you have an idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: Either a jar isn't present on the classpath or a JNI class isn't being found in the user(?).lib directory

Answer (score 0):

I know its been sometime you posted this question, but recently I encountered same issue and was able to solve it by add following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
    <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
    <version>20050927</version>
</dependency>
```